# qmake: How to have longer version numbers in .so file name

Tags: qmake

I'm trying to build a dynamic library on Linux using qmake. Here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE     = lib
TARGET       = soTest
DEPENDPATH  += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
VERSION      = 3.5.2.1
```

The problem is that when I use qmake to make the so file I get soTest.so.3.5.2, but what I need is soTest.3.5.2.1.

How can I get qmake to use the fourth number? (build number)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
 I figured it out.  I used "VER_PAT" which allowed me to put in the last octet.

Thanks.